# How can I edit cboxTitle in Colorbox

Tags: colorbox

I have descriptions in the title area of the colorbox image display, with the left and right arrows at the bottom of the picture like a caption. I forgot how on earth I edited it since it was a while ago and am going nuts trying to figure it out. Can someone point me in the right direction? Basically I have a description from the database which shows up, like "Title, Width, Height, Medium Description" and I just want to change the order a little.

Answer (score 1):

I finally figured it out, it's not in the jQuery colorbox which really should remain unaltered. Looks like I had a div in my php file and my changes were working except I neglected to change the echoed text description. So I had

```
<div class='single_image_div'>
<a class='gallery' href='../".$row['folder']."/".$row['location']."' title=

'".$row['title'].",&nbsp;".$row['sizeW']."W by ".$row['sizeH']."H,&nbsp;".$row['description']."  ' border='none'>

<img src='../".$row['folder']."/".$row['location']." 'border='0' > </a><br>
```

Whereas I changed the  order to:   $row['sizeH']."H by ".$row['sizeW'] (Height first and then Width)

I changed the sizeH with sizeW but neglected to change the 'H' with the 'W' so the numbers were coming in correctly like 12ft W by 10ft H but I didn't realize they were correct and just had to swap so the H (Height. So now it reads properly as 12ft H by 10ft W, same numbers but now correctly marked.

A tempest in a teapot